# ClassDefNotFoundException - but it was working fine right up until 10 minutes ago

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, google-maps-api-2

I'm currently working on an android app that needs to show a map with a location on it with a load of tagged photos at said location. For the past day and a half I've been wrestling to get google APIs working and now that the errors for them have (seemingly) gone, after importing a google play API project into Eclipse (as per the google reference), I'm now getting a ClassDefNotFoundException on my OnClick buttons. This did not occur but 10 minutes ago, before I referenced the API project.

I NEED to get this issue solved *today* so any help that can be supplied would really be most appreciated.

Here is a screenshot of the debug screen (and as you can see the class that is missing is supplied right next to it).

http://prntscr.com/155x4a

It ONLY happens when using this one button, every other button works perfectly fine.

GMapActivity.class

```
package com.pragsys.android.gps;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class GMapActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gmap);

        SupportMapFragment frag = new SupportMapFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, frag).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gmap, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pragsys.android.gps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.pragsys.android.gps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.pragsys.android.gps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <meta-data
             android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
             android:value="AIzaSyByBoq02A_DiWygIHdmidfVWVWrHWslbX4"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.pragsys.android.gps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TakePhotoActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_take_photo" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PhotoOverviewActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_photo_overview" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PhotoGalleryActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_photo_gallery" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PhotoUploadedActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_photo_uploaded" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AboutActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="-snip-" />

        <activity
            android:name=".GMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_gmap" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

layout.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Comment: have you referenced google play services library ??

Comment: Typically a NoClassDefFoundError signifies a problem with the way your project is set up in Eclipse and not your code. I would double check the way your libraries are set up, and try restarting eclipse and/or refreshing the project (which you can do by highlighting in the project explorer and hitting f5)

Comment: Yes, I have referenced google play services. Logcat told you exactly what I said - that there was a ClassDef missing for GMapActivity.class from an onClick handler, which was working 5 minutes ago.

Comment: I have answered my own question below. I think I have solved this specific error.. now I get to wonder why I'm only seeing +- buttons on the google maps :P

Comment: @Neglected This happens usually when the API key is incorrect.

Comment: @MaciejGórski I've verified the API key is correct. Now I'm just getting more errors. Retrieving the Fragment is null, for example. I suppose I should open a new question?

Answer (score 0):

-cue heavenly fanfare-
OK so I think I managed to solve the issue simply by changing

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

to

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

That'll teach me for just blindly copy-pasting from references.
EDIT: And for working until 3am into the night.